# How can I retrieve an integer from a SingleFlatMap in RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, reactive

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a Bluetooth Device.

```
if (rxBleDevice.connectionState != RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
 rxBleDevice!!.establishConnection(false) ? .subscribe({
  rxBleConnection ->

  Log.d("Device: ", "Connection Established")

  val stringDeviceUUID = rxBleDevice.bluetoothDevice.uuids[0].toString()
  val charUUID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(stringDeviceUUID.toByteArray())

  val count = rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(charUUID)

  println("OUTPUT: ${count}")

 }, {
  throwable -> Log.d("Device: ", "$throwable")
 })
}
```

I'm using the following dependencies, mainly RxJava and a reactive Bluetooth library called RxAndroidBLE:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
implementation "com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.8.1"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.7"
```

My output:

```
I/System.out: OUTPUT: io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap@bf9162d
```

I have no how to process this object. I believe I should be receiving a simple ByteArray from the Bluetooth device.

An example for the value I should see is `datc00099`, indicating a count of 99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to subscribe to `Single`. Following the examples provided by [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle), something like this might work in your case:

```
if (rxBleDevice.connectionState != RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.CONNECTED) {

 // Have your charUUID ready. Might need extra null checks for rxBleDevice
 val charUUID = rxBleDevice.bluetoothDevice.uuids[0].uuid

 rxBleDevice!!.establishConnection(false) ?
  .doOnNext {
   _ -> Log.d("Device: ", "Connection Established")
  } ?
  .flatMapSingle {
   rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(charUUID)
  } ? .subscribe({
   count ->
   // count should be in bytes
   println("OUTPUT: $count")

  }, {
   throwable ->
   Log.d("ERROR: ", "$throwable")
  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Unfortunately I am unable to retrieve the value because of a BleCharacteristicNotFoundException. I think the way I am creating UUIDs is a problem, though I am not certain. I posted my question here for anyone who is interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386104/com-polidea-rxandroidble2-exceptions-blecharacteristicnotfoundexception-charact